# GPU Memory is full directly after sequential model initialization and wont change during training

Tags: memory, tensorflow, gpu, keras, spyder

I am using Keras, on the backend tensorflow on windows 7 with the NVIDIA Quadro M2000M GPU.

When i initialization my model which contains 5 GRU, 5 Dropout and 1 Dense layers the GPU memory usage jumps to 3800MB of 4096MB and stays there until i restart my spyder session. Clearing the session within spyder with:

```
K.clear_session()
```

does not work. The Memory usage stays at that high level.

Is it normal that such a model allocate this much memory of the GPU? What can i change so the memory usage can be used proberly? I want to improve the training speed and i think this high memory usage hinder the GPU to use her full potential.

**Update**

My model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
layers = [1, 70, 50,100, 50,20, 1]

model.add(GRU(
        layers[1],
        #batch_size = 32,
        input_shape=(sequence_length, anzahl_features),
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_1))
model.add(GRU(
        layers[2],
        #batch_size = 32,
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_2))
model.add(GRU(
        layers[3],
        #batch_size = 32,
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_3))
model.add(GRU(
        layers[4],
        #batch_size = 32,
        return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_4))
model.add(GRU(
        layers[5],
        #batch_size = 32,
        return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(dropout_5))
model.add(Dense(
         layers[6]))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

My feature matrix has the size 506x500x35 (506  examples, 500 sequence length and 35 features). The batch size is set to 128. Site note: I am not saying that that is the perfect feature matrix or model configuration.

Here also a screenshot of GPU-Z where i restarted spyder and started the model until the second epoch:

[image]

[image: Model Summary]

Comment: how much data are you loading into the model?

Comment: There isn't enough information for us to estimate the memory footprint. How large are the inputs and layers? You also seem to have a misconception regarding GPU memory usage. If the necessary data and calculation outcomes are not in GPU memory, they have to be fetched from somewhere else, thus making the training process _slower_.

Comment: looks OK to me, you don't seem to be shuffling data over the bus a lot. Can you run `model.summary()` and get us the number of parameters of your model please? that way we can calculate whether this is justified.

Comment: Added the summary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default TensorFlow allocates the whole GPU memory.

If you want to have a better control on the GPU memory usage you can use these methods:

- the `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` config option, or
- the `allow_growth` config option.

Comment: That worked but my main problem with that is, that when i run the same configuration with my 8 CPUs the GPU is not much faster? Is it coused through the small data set, so not much can be parallelized?

Answer (score 0):

Let me just give the full piece of code how to control memory usage on your GPU:

```
    from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend 
    import set_session config = tf.ConfigProto() 

    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

GPU speed training might depends on your batch size, is it the same on CPU and GPU. Is it cuda installed